# Correct way of computing angle between geopoints

Tags: java, math, geolocation

I have a problem with calculation angle between lines created by connecting three geopoints.

```
p1
    \    p2
     \  /
     p3
```

I implemented many solutions but not gave me expected result. For example I used law of cosinuses [Direct way of computing clockwise angle between 2 vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066933/direct-way-of-computing-clockwise-angle-between-2-vectors/38679924#38679924) .
I also used equation

```
angle = atan2(vector2.y, vector2.x) - atan2(vector1.y, vector1.x).
```

Each method returned the same incorect result.

For example I have three points:

p3 latitude=52.66346360584388, 19.056108732273625

p1 latitude=52.66321959338828, 19.056379848488714

p2 latitude=52.66348185383115, 19.05648061759354

Law of cosinuses and atan2 returned angle 44.797 degrees. When I marker this points in google maps and measure the angle in gimp program I have about 57 degrees. In other sets of points the differences are the same or greater. What am I doing wrong?

[gimp angle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rY9MI.png)

Comment: Use spherical coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

For spherical  geometry you need to use special formulas [from here](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Look at bearing section, calculate bearings from p3 to p2 and from p3 to p1 and find their difference

```
Formula:    
  θ = atan2( sin Δλ ⋅ cos φ2 , cos φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 − sin φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ cos Δλ )
where   φ1,λ1 is the start point, 
   φ2,λ2 the end point (Δλ is the difference in longitude)

JavaScript:     (all angles     in radians)

var y = Math.sin(λ2-λ1) * Math.cos(φ2);
var x = Math.cos(φ1)*Math.sin(φ2) -
        Math.sin(φ1)*Math.cos(φ2)*Math.cos(λ2-λ1);
var brng = Math.atan2(y, x).toDegrees();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer solved my problems.