# How to calculate angles between the two column vectors?

Tags: python, vector, pyspark, databricks, angle

I'm using pyspark 3.1.2.

the schemas of `'Vector1'` and `'Vector2'` are both `VectorUDT`

```
  +----------+---------+
  |  Vector1 | Vector2 |
  +----------+---------+
  |[10.0,8.0]|[7.0,6.0]|
  | [3.0,5.0]|[9.0,2.0]|
  | [1.0,3.0]|[4.0,7.0]|
  | [1.0,5.0]|[9.0,3.0]|
  | [2.0,8.0]|[2.0,0.0]|
  | [8.0,7.0]|[3.0,6.0]|
  +----------+---------+
```

How to calculate angles between `Vector1` and `Vector2`?

I tried to:

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
angle_udf = F.udf(lambda x,y : x.dot(y) / (Vectors.norm(x,p=2) * Vectors.norm(y,p=2)),FloatType())
Vector = Vector.withColumn("Angle", angle_udf("Vector1","Vector2"))
```

But I didn't get the results I wanted.

Comment: Is [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066933/direct-way-of-computing-clockwise-angle-between-2-vectors) what you need ?

Comment: `angle = acos( dot(v_1,v_2)/(norm(v_1)*norm(v_2)) )`

Comment: How to calculate it in dataframe?

Comment: when looking at the official doc, vectors are used for ML but there are not "angle" methods related to this kind of object. but if you considere your vector as simply a array of coordinates, there are some basic sql function that you can use to compute angles (with acos or norm functions for example)

Answer (score 0):

To get the angle inbetween the two vectors I would suggest using the `atan2` builtin function with the follwoing formula:

angle = atan2(v2.y, v2.x) - atan2(v1.y, v1.x)

The PySpark implementation would look then like this assuming that the columns in your dataframe are labeled with `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2`:

```
df = df.withColumn('angle', f.atan2(f.col('y2'), f.col('x2')) - f.atan2(f.col('y1'), f.col('x1')))
```