# Calculating Internal Angles of Points Along Edges in a Polygon in Python

Tags: python, angle

I have a polygon that is defined as a list of its vertices in a clockwise direction. For a given point along one of the polygon's edges, I want to calculate the two degrees between which the 180 degrees of that point's interior angle lies.

For instance, if I have a polygon that is a rectangle with vertices:
`[(2, 0), (0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 2)]`, then I can expect `(1, 0)` to have between 0 and 180 degrees in an anticlockwise direction. `(0, 1)` would have between 90 and 270 degrees in a clockwise direction. Here is my code thus far; the function can identify the angle between but I have no way of knowing whether the interior should be clockwise or anticlockwise. I want to be able to tell whether to go clockwise or anticlockwise from `d1` to `d2` to get the internal angle.

```
def calculate_angle(self, point, vertice1, vertice2): # point between vertice1/vertice2

    x, y = point
    x1, y1 = v1
    x2, y2 = v2

    a = [(x - x1), (y - y1)]
    b = [(x - x2), (y - y2)]

    d1 = (math.degrees(atan2(a[1], a[0])) + 360) % 360
    d2 = (math.degrees(atan2(b[1], b[0])) + 360) % 360
                 
    d1, d2 = min([d1, d2]), max([d1, d2])
```

Comment: So, you want to ask "which side of d1 is the inside and which is the outside?"  That turns out to be a non-trivial problem for arbitrary polygons.  The traditional method is to shoot a line perpendicular to the point, and count how many polygon edges you cross.  If you cross an even number, it's the outside.  If you cross an odd number, it's the inside.  If your polygons are simpler, the code can be simpler.

Comment: we can check with this code
```clockwise_orientation = d1 > d2

    # Adjust the angle range based on the orientation
    if clockwise_orientation:
        d1, d2 = d2, d1
```

Comment: If the order of the points is vertice1, point, vertice2, in clockwise order around the polygon, then you are always interested in counterclockwise angle between vertice1 and vertice2. You could then use this formula, but with a negative in front of it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066933/direct-way-of-computing-the-clockwise-angle-between-two-vectors

Comment: BTW, this is tagged [convex-polygon]. Are all of your polygons convex? If so there is a very simple solution: always pick the direction which is less than 180 degrees.