# Unity find objects within range of two angles and with a max length (pie slice)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, range, angle

I've been programming an ability for a Hack n Slash which needs to check Units within a pie slice (or inbetween two angles with max length). But I'm stuck on how to check whether an unit is within the arc.

[Scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZvFE.png) (Not enough, rep for an image sorry im  new)

I currently use **Physics2D.OverlapSphere()** to get all of the objects within the maximum range. I then loop through all of the found objects to see whether they are within the two angles I specify. Yet this has janky results, probably because angles don't like negative values and value above 360.

How could I make this work or is there a better way to do this?
I probably need to change the way I check whether the angle is within the bounds.

Thanks in advance guys! I might respond with some delay as I won't be at my laptop for a couple hours.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static List<EntityBase> GetEntitiesInArc(Vector2 startPosition, float angle, float angularWidth, float radius)
{
    var colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(startPosition, radius, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Entity"));
    var targetList = new List<EntityBase>();

    var left = angle - angularWidth / 2f;
    var right = angle + angularWidth / 2f;

    foreach (var possibleTarget in colliders)
    {
        if (possibleTarget.GetComponent<EntityBase>())
        {
            var possibleTargetAngle = Vector2.Angle(startPosition, possibleTarget.transform.position);
            if (possibleTargetAngle >= left && possibleTargetAngle <= right)
            {
                targetList.Add(possibleTarget.GetComponent<EntityBase>());
            }
        }
    }

    return targetList;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding Signed Angle Between Vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150050/finding-signed-angle-between-vectors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Vector2.Angle(startPosition, possibleTarget.transform.position);

This is wrong. Imagine a line from the scene origin (0,0) to startPosition and a line to the transform.position. Vector2.Angle is giving you the angle between those two lines, which is not what you want to measure.

What you actually want is to give `GetEntitiesInArc` a forward vector then get the vector from the origin to the target position (`var directionToTarget = startPosition - possibleTarget.transform.position`) and measure `Vector2.Angle(forward, directionToTarget)`.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me out and it was a short and clean anwser!
The example that you gave made it easy to understand!